# Get Volume of trace

Tags: math, geometry, trace, volume

I would like to get the Volume of something that moves on a certain trajectory.
Let's take a cube e.g. if the cube moves in a straight line you would get a cuboid.
If this cube moves in a circular you get somehting like this:
[image]

Is there a Library out there that can calcutlate this for me with any given object and trajectory? Objects like a Toycar, Coke Bottle, drill etc.
What field of Mathematics am I in? I don't know the right words to google.

I know: C/++, Python,  bash and Matlab.
I am willing to learn new Languages.
If there is a CAD programm, thats fine with me too.

Cheers
Blusser

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a library for that: given the Surface Area of the Square as S and the length of your trace as T, the volume of the cuboid is S * T.
You have to adapt S to whatever shape is moving along the trace

Comment: How would I do this with an end mill?
How would i do this with a coke bottle.

Like I said, any given object, any given Trajectory